# Why Numpy.fromfile is not able to read the values of the entire file?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

My file contains 9976 values but while I am using the command
`fid = open('commemi2d0.1.node','r')`
`a = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.float64, sep=" ")`

it shows an Error message as:

**DeprecationWarning**: string or file could not be read to its end due to unmatched data; this will raise a ValueError in the future.

also
`a.shape` shows only 9975 values

Comment: If may help to see part of the file, especially the `tail`.  I don't know how a text file could end that would produce such an error.  Apparently there's something wrong with the file.

Comment: Here are the last few lines of my file:

2490    78116.16767212603  -134260.38123494756    0
2491    -64324.538641201798  -164748.63987219252    0
2492    72427.476345432719  161322.71845555468    0
2493    160912.73335697973  -160912.73335697973    0
# Generated by triangle -pq33Aa commemi2d0.poly

Comment: the comment line may be the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.